# How to refresh div tag content in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have 2 files.File1.php and File2.php. I created empty div1 tag inside File1.php which has File2.php contents. The File2.php contains one table with edit button in each row, inside div2 tag. When i Click on particular edit button, the div2 tag should get update and should get refresh without refreshing the whole page using jquery. Please suggest any idea...

File1.php

```
<div id="div1">
   //contains File2.php contents(below table)
</div>
```

File2.php

[image]

Comment: You can do this using ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Using ajax call

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "demo_test.php", success: function(result){
        $("#File2_content").html(result);
    }});
});
```

> in demo_test.php you have to target your process files

Comment: if the answer is Ok , can you please tick this answer as a correct answer ? :)

Comment: You need to use the id , what you want to update , my code is just a sample ... in this code if you write two #File2_content as id ,  File2_content will display twice ..